# Trying to copy specific columns in a row into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm very new to VBA. Trying to copy specific columns within a row if Column O has the text "Open". 
Have tried the code below and it works except it copies the entire row and I only want to copy the row but limited to columns E to Q. How do i insert the column range requirement?

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetA")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetB")

    j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("O13:O1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
        If c = "Open" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intersect(Source.Rows(c.Row), Source.Range("E:Q")).Copy Target.Rows(j)
```

or

```
Source.Range("E:Q").Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 Source.Rows(c.Row).Columns("E:Q").Copy Target.Rows(j)
```

You should be able to use Union to gather the qualifying ranges and paste in one go which will be more efficient

```
Public Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim c As Range, unionRng As Range
    Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetA")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetB")

    For Each c In Source.Range("O13:O1500")
        If c = "Open" Then
            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, Source.Rows(c.Row).Columns("E:Q"))
            Else
                Set unionRng = Source.Rows(c.Row).Columns("E:Q")
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.Copy Target.Range("A3")
End Sub
```

Comment: Any feedback at all please?

Answer (score 0):

While copying, you are trying to copy a specific range. So instead of using :

```
Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
```

Use

```
Source.Range("E*row*:Q*row*").Copy Target.Rows(j)
```

Where `*row*` is the row number. So you can copy Range from columns E to Q while keeping the row number fixed.

So the final code is

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim r As String 'Store the range here

Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetA")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetB")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("O10:O15")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "Open" Then
        r = "E" & c.Row & ":" & "Q" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Hope this helps !